# Can we use theoretically-impossible functions?

Tags: discussion

Title may be hard to understand, so an example:

If a language claim to have a busy beaver function `BB:unsigned int -> double`, and works fine(always return `Infinity` when input is a bit larger and output exceed `1e+310`), can we use it as one?

Comment: When/Why would you need to use such a function?

Comment: @user202729 Designed maybe for fun and used to generate a large number

Answer (score 9):

## No

Languages are defined by their implementations. If the implementation doesn't work, the feature doesn't exist.

Comment: So what's the line it differs to large memory request but without so many address wire?

Comment: They would work if there was more memory; lack of memory isn't the implementation's "fault". In contrast, if the program required an *infinite* amount of memory, it should be considered invalid.

Comment: No they need more *address*

Comment: That's still just a hardware/OS problem.

Comment: Consider C for example, it can only address 2^32 bytes in memory. If we move it to a 64 bit machine, it can access more than 4GB but can be considered a different implementation.

Comment: Another problem is that Busy Beaver is calculatable with enough(but not infinite) resource